# A logarithmic Calculation

Tags: logarithms

I have encountered a logarithmic question that I could not solve. Here is the question:

> $$\dfrac {\log 64}{\log4}+\dfrac {\log 8}{\log 2}$$
>
> A)1 B)2 C)3 D)5 E)6

Rules of Logarithm:

$$\log_a\left(\frac xy\right)=\log_ax-\log_ay$$

$$\log_ax^n=n\log_ax$$

Here is my calculation:

$$Q=\dfrac {\log 2^6}{\log 2^2}+\dfrac {\log 2^3}{\log 2}$$

$$Q=6\log 2-2\log 2+3\log 2-\log 2$$

$$Q=6\log 2$$
What is the error in my calculation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your second line is already wrong. You have to divide the logarithms, not subtract them. That said, the question is properly asked, so +1

Comment: What is the basis of what you denote $\log$?

Comment: 10. As far as I concerned, base is 10 when it is not denoted.

Comment: I edited your question using mathjax. You may want to learn it simple from here. "MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference - Mathematics Meta Stack Exchange" https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake was stated in the alternative answer

$$\log_yx=\frac {\log x}{\log y}≠\log \frac xy =\log x-\log y$$

Just use

$$\frac {\log x}{\log y} =\log _yx$$

We have

$$\frac {\log 64}{\log 4}=\log_4{64}=3$$

$$\frac {\log 8}{\log 2}=\log_28=3$$

Comment: I think you know that, for example $\log_4{64}=\log_4{4^3}=3\log_44=3$

Comment: Yes I know. Even though J.G. is the first answer, your answer is more elaborative.

Answer (score 2):

You've confused $\log x/\log y$ with $\log(x/y)$. Use the second rule twice, with $a=4$ ($a=2$) in the first (second) fraction.